# How to stub/mock statSync function of fs module in sinon

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocking, mocha.js, sinon

I've created a function to get folder stat and compare the created time. I'm trying to test it and in order to test all scenarios I'm trying to stub the return object of `statSync`. But I'm unable to do so.

**Actual function:**

```
export const isFolderOlderThanThreshold = (path: string) => {
  console.log('isFolderOlderThanThreshold');
  const rootFolderStat = statSync(path);
  console.log('rootFolderStat = ', rootFolderStat);
  const dateToCompare = new Date();
  dateToCompare.setTime(dateToCompare.getTime() - (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
  console.log('Creation time of folder %s is %s and threshold time is %s', path, rootFolderStat.birthtime, dateToCompare);
  return rootFolderStat.birthtimeMs <= dateToCompare.getTime();
};
```

**Test case:**

```
it('should check created time in upload folder', async () => {
    storageRepository.stubs.getRootStorageLocation.returns(rootStorageLocation);
    fs.mkdirSync(join(rootStorageLocation, 'aaa'));
    const date = new Date('2023-02-21T08:16:25.580Z');
    const obj = { birthtimeMs: BigInt(date.getTime()), birthtime: date } as fs.BigIntStats;
    const statSyncStub = sinon.stub(fs, "statSync").callsFake((path: fs.PathLike, options?: fs.StatSyncOptions | undefined) => {
      return obj;
    });
    // const statSyncStub = sinon.stub(fs, "statSync").returns(obj);
    // const statSyncStub = sinon.stub(fs, "statSync").resolves(obj);
    // const statSyncStub = sinon.stub(fs, "statSync").onFirstCall().resolves(obj);

    isFolderOlderThanThreshold(join(rootStorageLocation, 'aaa'));
    fs.rmSync(join(rootStorageLocation, 'aaa'), { recursive: true });
    console.log('statSyncStub.callCount = ', statSyncStub.callCount);
    statSyncStub.restore();
  });
});
```

I tried all the stubs mentioned in the test case. But it is printing the actual stat result and not the mocked one and the stub `callcount` is also 0.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where does the `statSync` function come from?

Comment: @LinDu it is coming from `fs` module which I'm trying to mock.